# Optimization Problem Notation

Tags: optimization, notation

Are the following notations equivalent for $\vec{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $f\colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ ?

$$\underset{\vec{x}}{\text{min}}\ f(\vec{x}) \overset{?}{=} \underset{x_1,\dots,x_n}{\text{min}}\ f(x_1,\dots,x_n)\overset{?}{=}\underset{x_1}{\text{min}}\left\{\ \underset{x_2}{\text{min}}\left\{\dots\underset{x_n}{\text{min}}\ f(x_1,\dots,x_n)\right\}\right\} $$

Comment: If your problem has no additional constraints yes!

Comment: Could you give me an example of when a constraint would make the equalities not hold?

Comment: Think about the linear program $\min\{3x_1+2x_2\,\colon x\geq0.5 , y\geq1 , x+y\geq 2\}$. If I remember correctly, you cant minimize variable-wise because there is a constraint involving more than 1 variable

Comment: @ArielSerranoni: I think you meant $x$ and $y$ instead of $x_1$ and $x_2$? Anyway, this is not a counterexample; minimizing first with respect to $x$, given $y$, yields $x=\max(0.5,2-y)$, a perfectly acceptable result, which can then be used in the outer minimization with respect to $y$ to complete the overall minimization. And even if it were not feasible to represent the result of the inner minimization in closed form, the notation would nevertheless be equivalent.

Comment: @joriki you’re saying the equalities are always true?

Answer (score 1):

I think the notations would be equivalent if you replaced $\min$ by $\inf$. However, with $\min$, you run into the problem that the inner minima may not exist. For instance, if you minimize $x^2\mathrm e^y$, the overall minimum is $0$ (attained on the line $x=0$), but in the componentwise minimization, the minimum over $y$ doesn't exist for $x\ne0$. The infimum, on the other hand, always exists; in this case the infimum over $y$ is $0$ for all $x$.

Comment: How would you put all of this together into a theorem that states when the equalities will hold? What are the necessary conditions for the equalities to hold?

Comment: @which988: I'd overlooked the fact that you were asking about more than one equality. The left-hand equality, as far as I'm aware, holds by definition -- I wouldn't know how the two sides could be taken to mean something different. I was only talking about the right-hand equality. For the right-hand equality, it's not a question of the equality holding but of both sides being defined. I don't think that the equality could fail to hold when both sides are defined. The condition for both sides to be defined are just that those minima exist -- I'm not sure what further conditions you seek.

Comment: I suppose I'm asking for a proof that the right most expression equals the left when the two sides are defined. It's not at all obvious to me that it should be true. For example, why should any ordering of the minimization produce the same result. I presented it with the minimization of $x_1$ at the outermost level and proceeded in ascending order from there. What if a different ordering was chosen, how would you prove that any ordering produces the same minimization?